# How to make one variable to multiple variables using php?

Tags: php

How to assign one variable to multiple variables using php?
Example:

```
$student = "Peter and Mary";
```

I want to get "Peter" and "Mary" string on the $student.

how to make the $student become two variable??
I hope the I can get the final result is

```
$var_name1 ="Peter";
$var_name2 ="Mary";
```

Is it using str_contains  or str_replace?????

Thank you very much

Comment: It looks like you are trying to split the $student variable. Look up the explode function. Using ' ' and your delimiter, that would give you an array of "Peter", "and" and "Mary". Your incoming data might addressing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$student = "Peter and Mary";
$student_arr = explode("and",$student);
print_r($student_arr);
```

> output =>    $student_arr[0] = "Peter";   $student_arr[1] = "Mary";